# (Bash) Evaluate text between tokens with command output in the file

Tags: perl, bash, sed, awk

I have text file, for example

> text text <%any_command "$(another_command)" parameter %> text text
>
> text * text <%any_command "$(another_command)" parameter %> text text

I need to evaluata text inside <% %> and replace it(including these tokens with result that) with the result of this evaluation.

how this could e done using akw or sed or perl?

i've tried to use sed without success:

`sed "s/<%\(.*\)%>/$(eval \1)/g"`

`-bash: 1: command not found`

UPDATE:

two additional requirements

1) It could be that where will be several commands to replace on the same line:

> text * text  <%any_command "$(another_command)" parameter %> text<%any_command "$(another_command)" parameter %>text

2) Any function could be placed inside the <%%> tags, for example we have any.sh file with the following content:

`#/bin/bash
function any_function
{
 echo $1
}`

and the line to be processed:

> text * text <% any_function 1 %> text text

Comment: not sur you could evaluate a value and dynamically reenter the result from sed in one line. Predefine a eval is possible but not from internal group substitution i think.

Comment: The error on your `sed` command is because you used double quotes instead of single quotes. The difference matters in many languages, including Unix shells.

Comment: i know. but if i will use single quotes the command eval will not be evaluated at all

Answer (score 1):

You could give this a shot:

```
perl -pi -e 's/<%(.*?)%>/$_=`$1`;chomp;$_;/ge' test.txt
```

which will capture the lines that match that pattern, shell out to run the command in bash, remove the trailing newline and replace the placeholder with the result.

When I run this with a sample file of:

```
text text <% date %> text text
text * text <% date %> text text
```

I got:

```
text text Mon Mar 24 09:12:13 EDT 2014 text text
text * text Mon Mar 24 09:12:13 EDT 2014 text text
```

as my result.

Comment: Your regular expression is greedy, multiple `<% ... %>` within a single line will not work.

Comment: Yes, that is one thing that doesn't work. And there is one more. Please find updates in the problem description.

Answer (score 1):

Don't believe this is possible as a single `sed` command. You could store the result of the command in a variable, then sub that back in:

```bash
while read line; do 
    result=$(echo "$line" | sed -r 's~.*<%(.*)%>.*~\1~' | bash)
    echo "$line" | sed -r "s~<%.*%>~$result~"
done < input.txt
```

This is somewhat sensitive to the commands themselves - the second `sed` command won't like it if the command contains newlines, for example, because the variable gets expanded before the command is actually run.

Input file:

```
text text <%head -1 /home/ooh/tmp/script%> text text
text * text <%echo "$(date +%Y/%m/%d)"%> text text
```

Output:

```
text text while read line; do  text text
text * text 2014/03/24 text text
```

Comment: It doesn't work in some cases. I've updated description - please find two new requirements I've added.